# Solve for the unknown

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

$31x-21^{21} \equiv 21+31^{31} \pmod 5$

The provided answers are:
$$
\left\{
3,8,13,18,...
\right.
$$

but I don't know how to get there. Can someone walk me through this please?

Comment: When solving an equation mod 5, multiples of $5$ are irrelevant, so you can replace $31x$ with $1x$ (since $30x$ is congruent to 0 mod 5). Try doing that with all the other terms. Also... $x^5$ is congruent to $x$, mod $5$, so $21^{21} = 21 \cdot 21^{20} = 21 \cdot (21^4)^5 = 21 \cdot 21^4$ (mod 5). Then you can notice that $21^4$ and $1^4$ are the same, mod 5. See where that gets you.

Comment: @JohnHughes It can be even easier than that actually, and you don't really have to apply Fermat's Little Theorem.

Comment: Agreed...but I figured that reinforcing that theorem might not be a bad idea, either. :)

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{split}
31x-21^{21} &\equiv 21+31^{31} &\pmod{5} \Longleftrightarrow\\
31x &\equiv 21+21^{21}+31^{31} &\pmod{5} \Longleftrightarrow\\
x   &\equiv21 + 21^{21}+31^{31} &\pmod{5}
\end{split}$$
Now you have at least two (and half) ways. You can notice that last digit is $1$, so last digit in any component of the sum will be $1$. I believe that you can finish it.

Second way is [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) ([Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem)). ($5$ is prime and $\gcd(21,5)=1 $ and $\gcd(31,5)=1$.)

However, you should receive $x \equiv 1+1+1 \pmod{5}$, so $x=5k+3$.

Comment: Thank you, I mistyped the question so this solution is not correct. It is helpful however.

Comment: The question has been edited, but it's interesting this "typo-ed" question has the same solution set.

Comment: However, I changed it, but everything is in edit history, if someone wants to look at it.

Answer (score 0):

$31x-21^{21} \equiv 21+31^{31} \pmod 5$

Because:

$31 \equiv 21 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$

it's as simple as:

$x - 1^{21} \equiv 1 + 1^{31} \pmod 5$

$x \equiv 1 + 1 + 1 = 3 \pmod 5$

So the solution is $x \equiv 3 \pmod 5$, which is basically what you have there in the listed solution set (well, just the positive values anyway).

Answer (score 0):

I understand the following is not a rigorous method, but its a start-
Intuitively, 
 21^21 always ends with 1, no matter what.
 31^31 ends with 1, no matter what.
 [31x - 21^21 - (21 +31^31)] mod 5  = 0 , implying the result should be divisible by 5 to satisfy the congruence.

This means that the result should end with a 0 or a 5. The one's place in (-21^21), (-21), (-31^31) brings down the congruence by -3 from the nearest zero, and -8 from the nearest 5. Hence, 31*x should be such that the one's place of 31*x should increase the equation value by 3, or by 8. Naturally, the solution sequence would be x =3, 8, 13, 18, etc- (since 31*3 has one's place =3, 31* 8 has 8, and so on.) Hope this makes sense.